# Экспорт из ubercart3

Tags: drupal

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем можно воспользоваться для экспорта нод из `ubercart3`. Желательно экспортировать в таком формате, в котором можно данные импортировать на другой сайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль [`feeds`](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) + модуль [`uc_feeds`](https://drupal.org/project/uc_feeds)